# How to get module information without loading it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know the `imp` module can be used in Python 3 to load modules and packages.

However, I'd like to get some information about a module (like `__version__`) before I actually loads it.

How can I get this information? I haven't found any useful method in `imp`.

Right now, I cannot see better than parsing myself the file found by `imp.find_module`.

Comment: How about importing the module, checking the version, and deleting it again from `sys.modules` if it turns out to be the wrong one?  If this is for some reason not an option, parsing the file with the `ast` module is certainly better than parsing it yourself.

Comment: Why do you want this? The reason why changes the answer.

Comment: I'm building a plugin manager, in which there is an AddonManager that displays loaded/available addons (like in modern browsers). Every addon must implement `__version__` and `__desc__` and I want to display these values for "available but not loaded addons".

Comment: @rds: I would then recommend that the modules must use Distribute, and be installed with pip. In that case you can parse the packages EGG-INFO directory (see answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what the module is, and if it's installed or not, etc. You want `__version__` for example, but there is nothing that is guaranteed to exist in a module. The standard attributes you have on a module, like `__cached__`, `__doc__`, `__file__`, `__name__`, `__package__` are all created when you import it.

If the module is not yet installed, ie it's a downloaded tgz or something, it will probably have a setup.py file, and then you can get a lot of information from that distribution if you extract it with `distutils`. I do this in [pyroma](https://bitbucket.org/regebro/pyroma), for example.

If it is installed it may have an EGG-INFO directory. In there you find a bunch of files, with a lot of information. Most of it is in the PKG-INFO file. For this to happen, each of your modules must use [Distribute](http://packages.python.org/distribute/) (or Setuptools).

If it has no EGG-INFO/PKG-INFO file then you will have to parse it. For `__version__` you can probably just do a regexp match. That will not be very generic, but then again, whatever information you look for will not be generic, and will most likely not exist unless you know exactly what module you are looking at.

For other things you might need a parser. `ast` is probably the best option there, although the parser in `lib2to3` has it's good sides as well.

Comment: egg-info seems to be a good idea. How will I be able to list candidates modules? My initial idea was to deploy the module in a subdirectory of my application, in which case a simple `dir.list()` produces the list.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. `__version__` is just name for an object the module creates while being executed. It doesn't exist until you execute the file that's responsible for defining the module. Parsing is one option, but it'll work only if the code defining `__version__` is trivial, e.g.

```
__version__ = 'some literal'
```

If it involves something more, then you have to execute the code at least partially.